# Why do I need to run diskpart clean when restoring a backup image to a brand new hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, diskpart

I was handed a brand new harddrive that came packaged and in an attempt to restore a backup image, it failed i.e. it does not restore the image and returns the message that the target drive is inconsistent.

I proceeded to format the new hard drive however was presented with the same message again.

Having contacted the vendor of the imaging software, I was informed I need to run the command `diskpart clean` on the target drive. What gets me is, I would have thought that a brand new hard drive would not have any partition table information. Is the incorrect? I also don't get how running diskpart clean resolves the issue.

There doesn't appear to be any information on the Interwebs regarding whether raw hard disks have partition tables or any code that needs to be wiped.

Comment: You may have just been unlucky in this one instance.

Comment: @randolph west - what do you mean by unlucky?

Comment: What Brian said below. It depends on the drive and manufacturer and distribution. You received one that wasn't recognised by the OS, ergo, "unlucky".

Answer (score 0):

Most new drives do come with a partition table and some are even pre-formated. It depends on what market it is being sold into - OEM bulk, boxed retail or system builders.

Comment: thanks. If it came pre-formatted or with a partition table, why would it appear as raw?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - It wouldn't have unless it was a filesystem that was understood by the OS.